# Firefox dropdown resizing issue

Tags: html, css

Take the following example:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="TestDropdown">
        <option value="Short" selected>Short</option>
        <option value="Long">A long description</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run this in **Firefox**, when you select a different choice in the dropdown the size of the select input changes.

I've figured out it is the padding 0 for * that is doing this.  However, if I change the padding to the select element instead of * then the dropdown is sized correctly.  So it must be something else * is applying padding to.

Any ideas?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LaDsh/

I can of course change the * to a list of tags and the problem will be removed, but curious to know what tag is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it myself.  Looking in the forms.css file for Firefox I saw there was a styling of:-

```
select > option {
  padding-top : 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  -moz-padding-start: 3px;
  -moz-padding-end: 5px;
}
```

So if I include this the issue is solved.